# how to make a generic sorting function in typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sorting, nested-object

I have an HTML table which is filled with data from an array of objects. The columns of this table are object properties.
I want the data to be sorted when any column header is clicked. However I'm finding it difficult to write a generic sorting function because objects that serve as input to the table have nested objects in them.
An example of what I mean:

Let's say there's an interface *Order*

```
export interface Order {
  date: string;
  paid: boolean;
  customer: {
    name: string;
    address: {
      city: string;
    }
  }
}
```

I then have an array for column data:

```
tableColumns: {colName: string; header: string}[] = [
  {colName: 'date', header: 'Date'},
  {colName: 'paid', header: 'Is paid'},
  {colName: 'customer.name', header: 'Name'},
  {colName: 'customer.address.city', header: 'City'}
]
```

The table is as follows:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th *ngFor="let col of tableColumns" (click)="sort(col.colName)">{{ col.header }}</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody *ngFor="let o of orders">
    <tr>
      <td>{{ o.date }}</td>
      <td>{{ o.paid }}</td>
      <td>{{ o.customer.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ o.customer.address.city }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And the sorting method:

```
sort(colName: string) {
  this.orders.sort((a, b) => a[colName] < b[colName] ? 1 : a[colName] > b[colName] ? -1 : 0)
}
```

Now obviously this will only work for *date* and *paid* and won't work for nested objects properties. I have an ugly workaround using if's but is there a way to make such method generic?

The workaround that I'm using now (not happy about it):

```
sort(colName: string) {
  if (colName === 'customer.name') {
    this.orders.sort((a, b) => a.customer.name < b.customer.name ? 1 : a.customer.name > b.customer.name ? -1 : 0)
  } else {
    this.orders.sort((a, b) => a[colName] < b[colName] ? 1 : a[colName] > b[colName] ? -1 : 0)
  }
}
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mba03N) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz That code definitely does what the poster requests, and I would consider it a more than satisfactory answer to the question.

Comment: @CoderApprentice I'm just concerned that I will write it up and ma_po will say "no, that's not what I meant" and then I'll have to spend even more time editing and fixing it.  Maybe it's unlikely, but I've been burned too many times.  If I don't hear back soon maybe I'll write it up regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Use an existing library instead of writing your own thing.  I would recommend [Ramda's **sortBy** function](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#sortBy).

```
sort(colName: string) {
  const path = R.path(colName.split('.'));
  this.orders = R.sortBy(path, this.orders);
}
```

In addition to **sortBy**, [**path**](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#sortBy) is used in the above solution to create a selector from *colName*.  Notice how **sortBy**, unlike Javascript's **Array.sort** function, *DOES NOT* sort an array in place.  The result must be reassigned to the *orders* property.  This is because all of Ramda's functions are pure functions that don't modify existing values.